# How to put a button down using flex?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

i ve using some issues using react-native with flexbox,
so i want to put the button to the down using flex-end but i can't so if there's someone who can help me i will be thankful.

```
    <View style={style.conatainer}>
              <Text style={style.text}> Welcome </Text>
                <View style={style.bottom}>
                  <Button 
                    icon="camera" 
                    mode="contained" 
                    onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')}>
                    Get started
                  </Button>
                </View>      


          </View>

    const style=StyleSheet.create({
  conatainer:{
    flex:1,
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center',

  },

  text:{
    fontSize:38,
    fontWeight:'200',
    backgroundColor:'#000',
    color:'#fff',
    display:'flex',
    justifyContent:'center',


  },

  bottom: {
    display:'flex',
    flexDirection:'column',
    justifyContent:'flex-end',
    height:'50%',
    backgroundColor:'#BDBDBD'

  },
  button:{
    display:'flex',
    justifyContent:'center',
    height:'100%'
  }
})
```

i'm all ears, for more details or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `align-self` to "flex-end", property to the `<button>`, check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/kLo9smyb/) fiddle.

Also, check this awesome reference guide for flex in [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

The gist of the fiddle:

```css
.component {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 20rem;
  background-color: #666;
}

.text {
  flex: 0 1;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.bottom {
  flex: 1 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: green;
}

.bottom button {
  flex: 0 1;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The button does not go down because it is affected by the center value set in the parent's view, `container`. Delete the center settings of the parent's view.

Remove `justifyContent` from `container`. and Remove `flexDirection` from `bottom`

```js
 import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,Button,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <View style={style.conatainer}>
              <Text style={style.text}> Welcome </Text>
                  <TouchableOpacity 
                    style={style.bottom}
                    icon="camera" 
                    mode="contained" 
                    onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')} >
                    <Text>Get started </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity> 
          </View>
    );
  }
}

    const style=StyleSheet.create({
  conatainer:{
    flex:1,
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center'
  },

  text:{
    fontSize:38,
    fontWeight:'200',
    backgroundColor:'#000',
    color:'#fff',
    display:'flex', 
  },

  bottom: {
    flex:1,
    justifyContent:'flex-end',
    backgroundColor:'#BDBDBD'

  },
});
```

Comment: @khaliloosbenk  I updated my answer. You can see your button at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create another container for the text

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={style.conatainer}>
        <View style={style.textContainer}>
          <Text style={style.text}>"Welcome"</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={style.bottom}>
          <Button
            icon="camera"
            style={style.button}
            onPress={() => console.log("Pressed")}
            title="Get started">
          </Button>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  conatainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  textContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 38,
    fontWeight: "200",
    backgroundColor: "#000",
    color: "#fff",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  bottom: {
    backgroundColor: "#BDBDBD",
    justifyContent: 'flex-end'
  },
  button: {
    height: 50
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I prepared a demo for you, I did what was told in Hong's answer. It worked in sandbox, so maybe there will be another issue in another place of your app.

I removed `justifyContent` from `conatainer` and `flexDirection` from `bottom`.

One thing that may be interesting to you is that flexbox is default (and only) display option in React Native. Therefore you don't have to tell any element to `display: flex` because it's already happening.

Link to working demo [is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-d2zr3)

So if there are any other issues, please let me know and I'll improve my answer.

Comment: thank u bro for ur time, but the same , i want to center the text "welcome "